# How to pass Dictionary Objects In HttpUrl In ANgular7?

Tags: angular7

First of all i wanna say sorry for that if my question is silly question,Iam confused with this because im new in Angular.

Before asking question i want to introduce about my code,

this is the get functon that exactly i have called api,

```
  get(feepaid_report: FeepaidReport): Observable<FeepaidReport[]> {
    const options = this._utils.makeOptions(this._headers);
    return this._http.get(`${this._feepaidreportUrl}`, options).pipe(
      map((res: Response) => res.json()),
      tap(
        data => this.afterGetRequest(),
        error => { console.log(error); }
      ));
  }
```

Here in this code _feepaidreportUrl is my baseUrl that looks like this:

```
private _feepaidreportUrl = `${new Config().api}/report/feepaid_report/`;
```

And the my argument feepaid_report of type FeepaidReport is comes with data of dictionary like this,

```
FeepaidReport: {paid_date: "2019-01-03", classes: "class12"}
```

And i want to append this dictionary (i.e feepaidreport data) in url so that i can pass the url for backend like that:

```
baseurl/?paid_date=2019-01-03&classes=class12
```

Hope you will understand my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above  problem is solved by doing this:

```
get(feepaid_report: FeepaidReport): Observable<FeepaidReport[]> {
  var url = `${this._feepaidreportUrl}/?`

   for(var key in feepaid_report){

      var val = feepaid_report[key];
       if (typeof(val) !=='undefined'){
        url = url + key + '=' + val + '&'
      }

    }



  const options = this._utils.makeOptions(this._headers);
    return this._http.get(url, options).pipe(
      map((res: Response) => res.json()),
      tap(
        data => this.afterGetRequest(),
        error => { console.log(error); }
      ));
  }
```